# Why isn't content-visibility:auto working in this simple example?

Tags: html, css

I've created two files, each with 100,000 `div` elements. The first is `slow.html`:

```html
<div>0.8562158266079849</div>
<div>0.9135280673563708</div>
...
<div>0.5053808333117775</div>
<div>0.9188260452433614</div>
```

and the second is `fast.html`:

```html
<style>
  div {
    content-visibility:auto;
    contain-intrinsic-size: 100vw 18.5px;
  }
</style>

<div>0.8562158266079849</div>
<div>0.9135280673563708</div>
...
<div>0.5053808333117775</div>
<div>0.9188260452433614</div>
```

As you can see, each `div` is just filled with a random decimal number. The only difference between `slow.html` and `fast.html` is that fast.html has that `<style>` block at the top.

`slow.html` takes about 2.7s to load:

[image: slow.html page load performance pie graph]

and `fast.html` takes about 17s to load:

[image: fast.html page load performance pie graph]

So [`content-visibility:auto`](https://web.dev/content-visibility/) has slowed down page load by quite a bit rather than speeding it up. Am I misunderstanding and/or misusing `content-visibility`? Is it not designed for the situation where I've got a large number of very *simple* elements?

My intended use-case is for helping speed up the rendering of tables of content where it's not worth it to implement virtual scrolling because they're just quick/scrappy/throwaway tools for internal analytics use.

I have tested on Chrome v89 and v90. Both have roughly the same load times.

Here's a one-liner to help you quickly replicate this:

```js
new Array(50000).fill(0).map(_ =>`<div>${Math.random()}</div>`).join("\n")
```

Note that using `content-visibility` and `contain-intrinsic-size` has worked as expected (massively reduces rendering time) in my previous tests, but it strangely doesn't work in this minimal example.

Comment: I would guess that setting the sizing is having more impact on performance rather than the visibility? Or do both pages have similar css?

Comment: @RachelGallen All the code for both pages is shown in the question - `slow.html` has no css. That said, letting the browser know about the size (via `contain-intrinsic-size`) is supposed to be a crucial part of speeding up the rendering with `content-visibility:auto`. It's a good idea you had to run some tests around that though (in case it helps track down a browser bug that's causing this) so I did try adding `<style>div { height: 18.5px; width: 190px; }</style>` to `slow.html`, but got the same result.

Comment: fair enough. It's a tricky one then! hmm...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out (explained to me by a Chromium dev) that the overhead of adding an intersection observer to each of the 100k elements (which Chromium does for `content-visibility:auto` elements) is expensive, and so it's not really designed for such a large number of elements.

It's possible that browser developers will make their algorithms more efficient in the future, but currently the best approach if you've got a lot of elements is to nest them into blocks (perhaps 1000 rows per block) which themselves have `content-visibility:auto`:

```html
<style>
  .block {
    content-visibility:auto;
    contain-intrinsic-size: 100vw 18500px;
  }
</style>

<div class="block">
  <div>0.8562158266079849</div>
  <div>0.9135280673563708</div>
  ...
  <div>0.5053808333117775</div>
  <div>0.9188260452433614</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div>0.5053808333117775</div>
  <div>0.9188260452433614</div>
  ...
  <div>0.8562158266079849</div>
  <div>0.9135280673563708</div>
</div>
...
```

Notice that since the blocks have 1000 divs that are each 18.5px in height, I've specified 18500px as the `contain-intrinsic-size` height.

This has the added benefit of removing the **layout** cost of all of the `div`s off-screen `block`s. The example in my original question only removed the **rendering** cost of the off-screen `div`s.

You can improve this further by nesting blocks within blocks (each with `content-visibility:auto` and a calculated `contain-intrinsic-size` height), such that only a very small number of elements need to be rendered and laid-out at any given time.